# Need to execute few commands on a linux server from windows and capture the output on windows command prompt using a python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute few linux commands on a linux server remotely from a windows server using a python script. The script is working fine and I'm able to execute the commands, however I need the output to be shown on the windows commandline. Now no output is shown on the commandline. Using Python 2.7. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code, and the error trace, if any, to better help you with your question. Also, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How are you executing the python script remotely?